# Why isnt the bird colliding with the ledges?

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, phaser-framework

I am making a flappy bird game using `phaser.js`.

My problem is that it doesn't collide with the ledges. And how do you change the camera (you know in flappy bird they like move the camera)?

Any other tips on making my game would be greatly appreciated!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okdp9x7g/)

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-demo', {

preload: preload,
  create: create,
  update: update,
  render: render
});

var player;
var starfield;
var cursors;
var fireButton;
var gameOver;
var upLedge;
var vaRandomUpLedgeSize;
var bottomLedge;



function preload() {
  game.load.image('starfield', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJAAAAEACAYAAABcV/9PAAAEWklEQVR42u3ZsW7UShSA4XltxAMgxGPwHHSwRSQaKpR0FCDRQY+AgAzeiccej8fesf0Vn8Llru2zJ//aubnh+bv3P6FUsAQEhIAQEAICASEgBISAQEAIiJYDevv7D1BIQAgIASEgBAQCQkDsKCC/DMNvohEQAkJAICAEhIAQEAgIASEgBAQCQkAICAGBgBAQAkJACAgEhIAQEAICASEgBISAQEAICAEhIBAQAkJACAgBgYAQEAJCQCAgBISAEBAICAEhIAQEAkJACAgBISBLQEAICAEhIBAQAkJACAgEhIAQEAICASEgBISAQEAICAEhIAQEAkJACAgBgYAQEAJCQCAgBISAEBAICAEhIASEgEBACAgBISAQEAJCQAgIBISAEBACAgEhIASEgEBACAgBISAEBAJCQAgIAYGAEBACQkAgIASEgBAQCAgBISAEhIBAQAgIATHD1x8PgwREUTh7Cykc9ZPR6t0iN5y97D0c9ZNxi7vF1F5K42l552FPn4ytZ6j5zV4aT+p93vr7EvbwyVhjjqlz1PiGd+erda6S+db8gD7+u1D7jbVwB1jzMbJXtT+g3d+FrYbc8vGx1iPkaBHVOGeTAd3qdn+miGqdL2xxq6zxWtq0akBrHsNBA0JAICAEhICuvfly+ef1x/snzjbHEXayeUAP3+/+eByq+3P3z2eb4wg7WRTQp28fnki9dqjqx+G6wZcsq5U5zriTUGu4nCH7VcdKltXKHGfeSZj7vE0NN1Rx/7xx1fHXuc/+VuY4+07CnNvlWN1DFXc/kOUOmTtLK3PYSXQHmio+Z8j+D2NDQ47dJnNnaWUOO7n/fwcaOih+fs65NZbcJnNmaWUOO/lrcUCpavu/U9hiWVvPYSdRQEMH5SwrdXx/yKk3FA85Nksrc9jJZbuAuq+3XlbNOezkst4jLPW83fp2veYcdrLiIywevv93OUPW+rStOYedzHyEpf7zcGzIscGXPDpaneOMO8l+hOX+gqr/P+OmBi99dLQ6xxl3ErqDh752wzy7e3El/l1DfFx/+PjY1PXi1835tKWOzTl36WNjbCdTj4742NT1au+k/70p3Ul87GhA3Ytefn51pR9DKqCpY+Nhxl6XWtbUsbkzzHls5OwkFdDedzJ0bBi61aUukvvGc46fe41uYTWvEX9D4jvC2XfSjyZ1XIhvYzlvYG7VU+fIOWfNawxdZ+haJTtZY94WdpI6dyj5BJR+YsbeyJJl5F5jzfd4lJ3MPXfIufBQlaWfyrl3sKXXyLlOSRhH3EnJucNat+Ean6yly6o9v51kBlTjFrnlebe4jp1kBlTrFrn0vEuXVfP1dpJ+TSgdCCZ/BgIBISAEhIBAQAgIASEgEBACQkAICAGBgBAQAkJAICAEhIAQEAgIASEgBAQCQkAICAEhIBAQAkJACAgEhIAQEAICASEgBISAQEAICAEhIBAQAkJACAgBgYAQEAJCQCAgBISAEBAICAHRlF+C+UHwNeMuEwAAAC10RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAYnkuYmxvb2RkeS5jcnlwdG8uaW1hZ2UuUE5HMjRFbmNvZGVyqAZ/7gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
  game.load.image('player', 'https://i.imgur.com/JArA3tQ.png');
  game.load.image('upLedge', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAACGCAYAAADZ0np4AAAAiklEQVR42u3UsQ2DQAwF0FslPT0jpE+BmIQBaLMDw2QUSpY45IIrTggFQVK94tvds2TJTnN+52npS4ZPU/q36cZH6ZFX+8wJDAaDwWAwGAwGg8FgMBgMBoPBYDAYDAaDwWAwGAwGg8FgMBgM3oej/CJpm3J30pUVHK0DDP4nHCd9JjG8fgP1Swh4Bcd7BZH+S2fyAAAALXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBieS5ibG9vZGR5LmNyeXB0by5pbWFnZS5QTkcyNEVuY29kZXKoBn/uAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  game.load.image('bottomLedge', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABUAAAB6CAYAAABQtRgZAAAAgklEQVR42u3TsQmAMBQFwKxib+8I9hbiJA5g6w4O4yiWLhFRUERslAgWF3h5pDmSwA9VUcbUCVPs45MMc3P0Xdoxj+F82PtN6i47GgpNja5b6oTPxvQ6Zk+/4fz07aZQKBQKhUKhUCgUCoVCoVAoFAqFQqFQKBQKhUKhUCj0n+gXawGd+WGo+T+h1gAAAC10RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAYnkuYmxvb2RkeS5jcnlwdG8uaW1hZ2UuUE5HMjRFbmNvZGVyqAZ/7gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');

}

function create() {
  //  The scrolling starfield background
  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

  starfield = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'starfield');
  starfield.scale.setTo(1, 2.5);
  starfield.enableBody = true;


  //  The hero!
  player = game.add.sprite(50, 400, 'player');
  player.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
  player.scale.setTo(1.25, 1.5);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
  game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  player.body.gravity.y = 450;
  player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;




  upLedge = game.add.sprite(400, 0, 'upLedge');
  bottomLedge = game.add.sprite(400, 365, 'bottomLedge');

  randomLedgeSize();
  upLedge.scale.setTo(1, vaRandomUpLedgeSize);

  randomLedgeSize();
  bottomLedge.scale.setTo(1, vaRandomUpLedgeSize);



  fireButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
  //  And some controls to play the game with
  cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update() {
  //  Scroll the background
  starfield.tilePosition.x -= 2;

  player.x++;
  //SPACEBAR 
  if (player.y >= 591.75) {
    player.y = 591.75;
    player.x--;


  }
  if (fireButton.isDown) {
    player.body.velocity.y = -250;
  }

  game.physics.arcade.collide(player, upLedge);
  game.physics.arcade.collide(player, bottomLedge);

}

function render() {

}

function randomLedgeSize() {
  vaRandomUpLedgeSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1)) + 1;

  if (vaRandomUpLedgeSize <= 1.5) {
    vaRandomUpLedgeSize = 1;
  } else {
    vaRandomUpLedgeSize = 2;
  }
}

function randomLedgeSizeBot() {
  vaRandomUpLedgeSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1)) + 1;

  if (vaRandomUpLedgeSize <= 1.5) {
    bottomLedge.y = 500;
  } else {
    vaRandomUpLedgeSize = 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI - you have defined the function `randomLedgeSize` twice

Comment: Yes i did it on purpose Oh nvm the second one should be randomLedgeSizeBot(); Oh gosh

Comment: And what would that purpose be?

Comment: Still not colliding :( Im about to edit new code on JSFiddle Sorry for that mistake!

Comment: I've been looking at this since you posted. I can't figure it out either. I don't know this framework, and I'm looking at their example. http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/one-way-collision#gv
I can't for the life of me figure out why sprite 3 is not reacting the same way as sprite 2. They have the same code it looks like!

Comment: Well, i got it to collide with the top part of the ledge, I'm not sure whats going on. https://jsfiddle.net/mmo3y1dz/

Comment: christopher clark! Thanks a lot!!! would love if the player can collide with the actual ledge but i wil try to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3300-collision-between-sprites-not-working/?p=21412):

> The collisions only fire if the **sprite.body** has velocity.

So what I did was change the `update()` function: I removed the call to `player.x++;` and in the `create()` function I added an X velocity to the player.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5180tggc/)

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-demo', {
  preload: preload,
  create: create,
  update: update,
  render: render
});

var player;
var starfield;
var cursors;
var fireButton;
var gameOver;
var ledges;

function preload() {
  game.load.image('starfield', 'data:image/png;base64,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');
  game.load.image('player', 'https://i.imgur.com/JArA3tQ.png');
  game.load.image('upLedge', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAACGCAYAAADZ0np4AAAAiklEQVR42u3UsQ2DQAwF0FslPT0jpE+BmIQBaLMDw2QUSpY45IIrTggFQVK94tvds2TJTnN+52npS4ZPU/q36cZH6ZFX+8wJDAaDwWAwGAwGg8FgMBgMBoPBYDAYDAaDwWAwGAwGg8FgMBgM3oej/CJpm3J30pUVHK0DDP4nHCd9JjG8fgP1Swh4Bcd7BZH+S2fyAAAALXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBieS5ibG9vZGR5LmNyeXB0by5pbWFnZS5QTkcyNEVuY29kZXKoBn/uAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  game.load.image('bottomLedge', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABUAAAB6CAYAAABQtRgZAAAAgklEQVR42u3TsQmAMBQFwKxib+8I9hbiJA5g6w4O4yiWLhFRUERslAgWF3h5pDmSwA9VUcbUCVPs45MMc3P0Xdoxj+F82PtN6i47GgpNja5b6oTPxvQ6Zk+/4fz07aZQKBQKhUKhUCgUCoVCoVAoFAqFQqFQKBQKhUKhUCj0n+gXawGd+WGo+T+h1gAAAC10RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAYnkuYmxvb2RkeS5jcnlwdG8uaW1hZ2UuUE5HMjRFbmNvZGVyqAZ/7gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');

}

function create() {
  //  The scrolling starfield background
  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

  starfield = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'starfield');
  starfield.scale.setTo(1, 2.5);

  //  The hero!
  player = game.add.sprite(50, 400, 'player');
  player.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
  player.scale.setTo(1.25, 1.5);  
  game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
  game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  player.enableBody = true;
  player.body.gravity.y = 450;
  player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
  player.body.velocity.x = 100;

  // The ledges
  ledges = game.add.group();
  ledges.enableBody = true;
  var upLedge = ledges.create(200, 0, 'upLedge');
  upLedge.body.immovable = true;
  var bottomLedge = ledges.create(200, 465, 'bottomLedge');
  bottomLedge.body.immovable = true;

  //  Controls to play the game with
  fireButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
  cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update() {
  //  Scroll the background
  starfield.tilePosition.x -= 2;

  // If spacebar is pressed, increase Y velocity
  if (fireButton.isDown) {
    player.body.velocity.y = -250;
  }

    // Check for collisions
  game.physics.arcade.collide(player, ledges);
}

function render() {
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any other tips on making the game? On how to make it endless?